# i cant get my program to work i keep getting undefined symbol: c

Tags: c++, linux, systems-programming

I'm trying to load all the libraries, and call a function from each one, to create a file and shate the fiddle thru the pointer, and write stuff in the main program with them, the close them.

This is my main function:

```c
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char LIBA[]="./LIBA.SO";
char LIBB[]="./LIBB.SO";
char LIBC[]="./LIBC.SO";
typedef void (*FUNC_T)(int*);
FUNC_T FUNC[2];

void ifnull(void *detect)
{
    if (detect == NULL)
    {
        cout << "ERROR:" << dlerror() << endl;
        exit(-1);    
    }
}

void ifnull2(FUNC_T detect)
{
    if (detect == NULL)
    {
        cout << "ERROR:" << dlerror() << endl;
       exit(-1);    
    }
}

int main()
{
    void *handle[2];
    int FD[2];
    handle[0]=dlopen(LIBA, RTLD_LAZY); ifnull(handle[0]);
    handle[1]=dlopen(LIBB, RTLD_NOW); ifnull(handle[1]);
    handle[2]=dlopen(LIBC, RTLD_NOW); ifnull(handle[2]);        
    FUNC[0]=(void(*)(int*))dlsym(handle[0], "c"); ifnull2(FUNC[0]);
    FUNC[1]=(void(*)(int*))dlsym(handle[1], "c"); ifnull2(FUNC[1]);
    FUNC[2]=(void(*)(int*))dlsym(handle[2], "c"); ifnull2(FUNC[2]);

    FUNC[0](&FD[0]); FUNC[1](&FD[1]); FUNC[2](&FD[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

This is inside the libs:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void c(int *fd)
{
    printf("ok A\n");
}
```

I keep getting

```
ERROR:./LIBA.SO: undefined symbol: c
```

please help

Comment: Please don't tag with languages other than the one you are using.

Comment: `void *handle[2];` is a two-element array, there's no `handle[2]`...

Comment: In C++ file scope is static, which makes the symbol private to the translation unit. Sometimes `const` will become private, too. You need to explicitly add the `extern` keyword to export the symbol. This is slightly different behavior than C.

Comment: These should be constant string literals, like `const char LIBA[]="./LIBA.SO";`. If you want to the symbols visible outside the translation unit, then export them:  `extern const char LIBA[]="./LIBA.SO";`.

Comment: pretty much all his arrays are 1 short

Comment: thanks you all :) ill try this now

Comment: Are those C or C++ libraries? I suspect that you've encountered the name mangling of C++.

Comment: What is "shate the fiddle"? Typo for "share the file"?

Comment: adding extern to the strings, doesnt work, and i have know idea what it would do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ mungs function names because it can have multiple functions with the same name.

So, for

```
#include <stdio.h>

void c(int *fd)
{
    printf("ok A\n");
}
```

we get

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c -fPIC liba.cpp -o liba.so
liba.cpp: In function ‘void c(int*)’:
liba.cpp:3:13: warning: unused parameter ‘fd’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 void c(int *fd)
             ^~

$ nm liba.so
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 U puts
0000000000000000 T _Z1cPi
```

As you can see, the function exists as `_Z1cPi`. I'm not sure if that's safe to use. What you can do, however, is use `extern "C"`.

For

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C" void c(int *fd)
{
    printf("ok A\n");
}
```

we get

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c -fPIC liba.cpp -o liba.so
liba.cpp: In function ‘void c(int*)’:
liba.cpp:3:24: warning: unused parameter ‘fd’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 extern "C" void c(int *fd)
                        ^~

$ nm liba.so
0000000000000000 T c
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 U puts
```

Comment: _function exists as `_Z1cPi`. I'm not sure if that's safe to use._ C++ name mangling is not standardized AFAIK. I wouldn't rely on any name mangling. (I'm not sure how this interferes with the ABI topic.) However, for portable code (where Windows and VC++ may play a role), `extern "C"` seems to me the only reliable solution.

Comment: I found another Q/A about this: [SO: Why is name mangling not standardized](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10127982/7478597).